# Overriding Hashcode in a class with one field v verriding Hashcode in a class with many fields?

Tags: c#

Please see this question, which I asked recently: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186379/equality-comparison-for-a-surname-value-object-class

Under the question Zack advises that my Hashcode adds unnecessary complexity.

1) Say I have an object with more than three fields (field1, field2 and field3).  I believe this is the proposed HashCode:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
    {
        int hash = 17;
        // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
        hash = hash * 23 + field1.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + field2.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + field3.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

2) Say I have an object with more than one fields (field1).  I believe this is the proposed HashCode:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return field1.GetHashCode();
}
```

Have I understood this correctly? What is the point of unchecked in the first sample?

Comment: `unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap`

Comment: @Gusman, what do you mean?

Comment: `Overflow is fine, just wrap`, that explains all, if you overflow the `Int32.MaxValue` it will roll to `Int32.MinValue`.

Comment: I think you think "more than" means something other than what it actually means. Note that `unchecked` is required here only if you compile with the `-checked` compiler option. By default, arithmetic is checked at compile-time (i.e. for numeric literals) and unchecked at runtime. One would typically only see `unchecked` in code where `-checked` is explicitly being used, or in a library where one might not know the state of checked.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the point of unchecked in the first sample?

By multiplying and adding all the single hashcodes together you very likely will hit the `Int32.MaxValue` limit wich can cause an `OverflowException`.
As it is fine to just "wrap" (=continue at `Int32.MinValue`) in that case you mark that block as `unchecked` and no exception will be thrown.